# How to block visitors from google from accessing files?

Tags: .htaccess, indexing

There is a directory of PDF files that has been indexed by Google and that should be private. As I already fixed this by creating robots.txt and directory listing, some time will have to pass until Google removes the links.

Can I block access to those files using htaccess if a visitor is coming from Google?

Comment: Why not just move the files to a different directory that google didn't index? Then update the links in your application for users that should be able to have access?

Comment: Matt, links has been sent over email and other resources to people so it would be better to keep the directory.

Comment: If files are private, set up some authentication, e.g. htpasswd or similar